# Trying to clear all customers on clicking the clear button. Also remove a customer on deleting a customer

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, click

https://github.com/Rengkat/OOP-Customer-List.git

Trying to clear all customers on clicking the clear button. Also, remove a customer on deleting a customer

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error you have encountered?

Comment: Trying to clear all customers on clicking the clear button. Also, remove a customer on deleting a customer. I try, but the buttons are not working. the code is on my Github

Comment: Does my answer fulfill your request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quick fix, each time a customer is added, you should also give parent div an id match its customer's id

```
    //new div for a customer
    const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    //seting a class for the div
    newDiv.className = "flex-child";
    newDiv.id = customer.id;    //Here
```

And data to delete customer button

```
<button class="button u-full-width customer-btn" data-cust="${customer.id}">
    DELETE CUSTOMER
</button>`;
```

With this, you can easily get the data and find the component to delete a customer

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("customer-btn")) {
    let cust = event.target.dataset.cust;
    document.getElementById(cust).remove();
  }
});
```

Delete all customer is easier, just wipe out its innerHTML and you're done

```
  deletAllCustomers() {
    document.getElementById("row").innerHTML = "";
  }
```